# Cannot convert List<List<double>> to List<double>

Tags: c#, list

I created a list which has 100 list each with 60 values, I need to run all of those 6000 values held within the list called population through a test (shown at the bottom error) and im not sure how i would go about converting the `List<List<double>>` to `List<double>`, or if i even can

[image: ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/eByu6.png]

Comment: Insert code as code, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your code and think the following code can help you.

```
class Program
{
    public static Random _random = new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<List<double>> population = new List<List<double>>();

        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
        {
            var gWeights = new List<double>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
            {
                var random = (_random.NextDouble() * 2) - 1;
                gWeights.Add(random);
            }
            population.Add(gWeights);
        }

        List<double> population2 = new List<double>();

        population.ForEach(x => population2.AddRange(x));
        GetResult(population2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void GetResult(List<double> items)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your help could i ask you just to be sure what does the section with list population2 and the population.ForEach(x => population2.AddRange(x)); do.

Comment: I wanted a new list to include each of the population items so I created population2

Answer (score 2):

You can either start off with a `List<double>` and use `AddRange`, so that you flatten the collections. Or you can convert it using `SelectMany`, like this:

```
var list = new List<double>();
foreach (...)
{
    list.AddRange(someOtherList);
}

// Or

var list = new List<List<double>>();
var flattenedList = list.SelectMany(x => x);
```